# Using N prefix in sql server parameters

Tags: sql-server

In my where clause if I write `AND acts.displayname = N'Onaylanmış Rapor'`  I get the results that I want. But for parameterizing the query I found out that NVARCHAR(MAX) parameters are still returning VARCHAR results without special characters and all.

A sample for my problem is like this;

```
    DECLARE @displayname NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @displayname = 'Onaylanmış Rapor'



    select @displayname as param, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@displayname) as nvarconvert, CAST(@displayname as NVARCHAR(MAX)) as nvarcharcast


+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|      param       |   nvarconvert    |   nvarcharcast   |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Onaylanmis Rapor | Onaylanmis Rapor | Onaylanmis Rapor |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I still need the parameter as '`Onaylanmış Rapor`' though.

I tried casting and converting the parameter value into nvarchar(max) but it doesn't work either.

Is there any other way?

Comment: You can cast and convert all you like, but the *input literal* needs to be able to contain the characters. `N'Onaylanmış Rapor'` is a Unicode literal and works, `'Onaylanmış Rapor'` does not. After the variable has already been assigned, converting does nothing. If your parameters aren't working despite being `N(VAR)CHAR`, you need to investigate the client code issuing the query.

Comment: SET @displayname = N'Onaylanmış Rapor'

Answer (score 3):

SET @displayname = 'Onaylanmış Rapor' by having a string in apostrophe it is being implicitly converted to non unicode.  You need the unicode identifier in your hard coded string.

```
DECLARE @displayname NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @displayname = N'Onaylanmış Rapor'



select @displayname as param, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@displayname) as nvarconvert, CAST(@displayname as NVARCHAR(MAX)) as nvarcharcast
```